# Remove directory failed even as root

Tags: alma-linux

I am trying to remove a directory and it fails:

```
[root@pmds-n48 autoit]# rm -rf /home/pick/.gvfs
rm: cannot remove '/home/pick/.gvfs': Is a directory
```

When I checked the permission, it has all ?

```
d??????????  ? ?    ?             ?            ? .gvfs
```

`selinux` has been disabled and there are no errors in the logs.

Comment: Is this a fuse/sshfs or a samba share? Can you share code how you connect/bind/mount?

Answer (score 0):

The question marks in the file information indicate that you have no permissions to run a  `stat()` system call on the directory. Most often, it means you have only `r` but not `x` permission to the directory the target is in, i.e. `/home/pick`. See `ls -ld /home/pick` to verify.

Also note that if `/home` is a NFS share mounted from another server, the server computer can restrict the `root` of the NFS client computer to be the equivalent of `nobody` when accessing the share. This is done at the NFS server side, often by default, and overcoming it may require a `no_root_squash` export option for the share at the NFS server.

Making the root of the NFS client powerless on a NFS share is a security mechanism that prevents someone that has managed to gain illegitimate root access to the NFS client from easily getting root in the NFS server too.